Is there a difference between a prisoner of war and a Slave in the sharia
I was talking to someone and he said “Prisoner of war automatically fall into slavery“ I said “no there is a difference between a slave and a prisoner of war in the sharia.” can anyone prove that there is a difference between a slave and a prisoner of war. Also bring proofs With scholars, Quran, Hadith, seerah.

There is obviously a difference because it is possible that a prisoner might not be enslaved and it is also possible that a slave might never have been a prisoner of war. However the person you talked to might be referring to the fact that women and children are automatically enslaved when captured according to some madhabs. See What are the sources of slavery in Islam?
